# Remote desktop application that runs on Wayland (alternative to Teamviewer)

Tags: gratis, linux, remote-desktop

Teamviewer runs on Linux but not on wayland, I'm looking for a team viewer alternative that:

- Is free
- Runs on Linux wayland, primarily ubuntu 18.04
- Not Anydesk, because it causes too many issues with the audio drivers and volume slider
- Is cross platform, in case I'm talking to someone who doesn't use Linux

Teamviewer is a remote desktop application, so lets say you have a problem and you need me to help you, we both run Teamviewer, I can see your screen, control your PC, talk to using the microphone and send you files, all through Teamviewer, when the problem is fixed, we end the session.

Xorg and Wayland are the display managers for Linux. Wayland is newer than Xorg and is used as the default display manager on most Linux. Its security features prevent Teamviewer from working, teamviewer promises to fix that, soon, they made the promise in 2017, I don't know if they're ever going to do that.

While It's still possible to switch to Xorg, restarting the PC each time you want to run Teamviewer is not practical, and setting Xorg as the default display manager, causes more harm than good.

Comment: The acronym VNC (for [Virtual Network Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing)) will come in useful in your search. Google gives some help for `vnc wayland windows`